# Ext JS 4: Setting a different root node for a TreeStore

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4, treeview, store

I'm trying to set a different root node in my TreeStore in Ext JS 4.0.7, but I can't seem to do it correctly... I don't know if it's another bug in the framework or if I'm just using the functions incorrectly, so I'm asking for help.  Here is the code that I'm working with.

**Creating a blank node to use later on**

```
var node = {
  id: 'root',
  text: 'root',
  expanded: true,
  children: [{
    id: 'child1',
    text: 'child1',
    leaf: true
  },{
    id: 'child2',
    text: 'child2',
    leaf: true
  }]
};
```

**The store**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  storeId: 'treestore',
  proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  },
  snapshot: node,
  root: {
    id: 'root',
    text: 'root',
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
      id: 'dummy1',
      text: 'dummy1',
      leaf: true
    },{
      id: 'dummy2',
      text: 'dummy2',
      leaf: true
    }]
  }
});
```

**Tree Panel**

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
  store: store,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  height: 600,
  width: 600,
  id: 'mytree',
  tbar: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'set child1 as root',
    handler: function() {
      var store = Ext.getCmp('mytree').store;
      store.setRootNode(store.snapshot);
      alert(store.getNodeById('child1').data.id);  // alerts child1
    }
  },{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'set dummy1 as root',
    handler: function() {
      var store = Ext.getCmp('mytree').store;
      store.setRootNode(store.snapshot2.copy(null, true));
      alert(store.getNodeById('dummy1'));  // alerts undefined
    }
  },{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'set dummy1 with diff copy',
    handler: function() {
      var store = Ext.getCmp('mytree').store;
      store.getRootNode().removeAll();
      store.snapshot2.eachChild(function(rec) {
        store.getRootNode().appendChild(rec.copy(null, true));
      });
      alert(store.getNodeById('dummy1').data.id);  // alerts dummy1
    }
  }]
});
```

**Setting snapshot2 to the store's current root node**

```
Ext.getCmp('mytree').store.snapshot2 = Ext.getCmp('mytree').store.getRootNode().copy(null, true);
```

So when you click the first button, you get the proper value ('child1') in the alert.  However, when you click the second button ('set dummy1 as root'), you get undefined in the alert.  The third button gives you the proper output ('dummy1'), and manually deep copies each child to the root.

To me, it seems like the copy function or the setRootNode function isn't doing something properly (leaning more toward the former).  If I'm specifying a deep copy with `copy(null, true)`, then the deep copy should be taking place, and everything should be fine... but I realize there's a problem with the copy function from the get go (see this [thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134844-tree-node-copy%28deep%29-not-working-%284.0.1)).  That's why I'm thinking it could be with the setRootNode, but that wouldn't make sense if setRootNode works for my created node but not for the deep copied original root node.

Can anyone offer any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?  I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think copy has a bug that still hasn't been resolved:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134844-tree-node-copy%28deep%29-not-working-%284.0.1%29&highlight=tree%20copy

Comment: Yep, I even referenced that thread in my post, but it goes deeper than that because I even applied the fix.

Comment: Apparently this has since been resolved... marking your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your problem is in the above code, but I can offer a "better" way - this one works, at least, I think it also does what you're intending here:

**Define two nodes - the snapshot and the root**

```
var node = {
    id: 'root',
    text: 'root',
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        id: 'child1',
        text: 'child1',
        leaf: true 
    },{  
        id: 'child2',
        text: 'child2',
        leaf: true 
    }]   
};   

var rootNode = {
    id: 'root',
    text: 'root',
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        id: 'dummy1',
        text: 'dummy1',
        leaf: true 
    },{  
        id: 'dummy2',
        text: 'dummy2',
        leaf: true 
    }]   
};
```

**Then, define your store and functions (scrapping snapshot2)**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    storeId: 'treestore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    snapshot: node,
    root: rootNode
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 600,
    width: 600,
    id: 'mytree',
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'set child1 as root',
        handler: function() {
            var store = Ext.getCmp('mytree').store;
            store.setRootNode(store.snapshot);
            alert(store.getNodeById('child1').data.id);  // alerts child1
        }
    },'->', {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'set dummy1 as root',
        handler: function() {
            var store = Ext.getCmp('mytree').store;
            store.setRootNode(rootNode);
            alert(store.getNodeById('dummy1').data.id);  // now alerts dummy1
        }
    }]
```

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but my initial post was to prove that a the copy function didn't seem to copy properly...